# Update Amcharts4 chart dynamically using vue js

Tags: vue.js, amcharts, amcharts4

I'm using [AmCharts4](https://www.amcharts.com) with Vue.JS,

For the moment I've added default chart design when page loads, But when I trying to add dynamic values after page loads (Using Button click), It doesn't reflect on view.

Code:- [gist](https://gist.github.com/chinthaka-dinadasa/d68596205f3bd5d86550908ccdaee492)

`data: () => ({
            dataForChart: {
                data: [{
                    "name": "Anne",
                    "steps": 32
                }, {
                    "name": "Rose",
                    "steps": 30
                }, {
                    "name": "Jane",
                    "steps": 25
                }]
            }
        }),`

chart creation on `mounted()`

`let chart = am4core.create("chart-div", am4charts.XYChart);
chart.data = this.dataForChart.data`

when dynamically change values using button click those data doesnt reflect on chart.

method followed to change data set.

`this.dataForChart.data = {
                data: [{
                    "name": "Anne",
                    "steps": 54
                }, {
                    "name": "Rose",
                    "steps": 44
                }, {
                    "name": "Jane",
                    "steps": 33
                }]
            }`

Comment: Can you please share a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) so we can reproduce your issue?

Comment: @SamuelPhilipp Done

Answer (score 3):

The reason for this is that although this.dataForChart.data is reactive (it's a vue instance property) the chart.data (amcharts chart property) is not.

You have to manually set chart.data array values whenever your this.dataForChart.data property changes. I've done this by setting a watcher on this.dataForChart.data like so:

```
watch: {
            dataForChart: {
                data(values) {
                    this.chart.data = values;
                },
                deep: true
            }
        }
```

Cheers!